# Opening a link on new tab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to open a link in a `<a>` tag in a new tab/window, do something there and then close it.

html code:

```
<body>
    <a id="uniqueid" href="somelink">I need to open this in a new tab</a>
</body>
```

python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver")

driver.get("url")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("uniqueid")

# I need to do this somehow
element.open_on_new_tab()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to get the url from the `"uniqueid"` element:

```
url = element.get_attribute('href')
```

Then you get that page, change into it with **Ctrl-TAB**, and do something there:

```
# Save current window
w0 = drv.window_handles[0]

# Create new window, make it the active tab
drv.execute_script("window.open('" + url + "');")
drv.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
sleep(3)
w1 = drv.window_handles[1]

# Change to the new window
drv.switch_to.window(w1)

# Do something here
```

After that you can switch back to `w0` if needed:

```
drv.switch_to.window(w0)
```